# All the regular $n$-gons are nested tightly around a unit circle. How to order them to minimize the outer radius, and what is that minimum radius?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, permutations, polygons

Let $u_1,u_2,u_3,\dots$ be a permutation of the integers greater than $2$.

A unit circle is in a regular $u_1$-gon, which is a regular $u_2$-gon, which is in a regular $u_3$-gon, *ad infinitum*. Each polygon is as small as possible (they do not have to be concentric).

> What permutation $u_1,u_2,u_3,\dots$ minimizes $R$, the [radius](https://www.mathopenref.com/polygonradius.html) of the outermost polygon?
> And what is an approximation of that minimum $R$?

Could the optimal permutation just be $3,4,5,\dots$ ?

Based on page 7 of [Tightly Circumscribed Regular Polygons](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6293.pdf#:%7E:text=regular%20polygon%20circumscribing%20another%20regular%20polygon%20%28with%20a,drawing%20intermediate%20spacing%20circles%20between%20the%20polygon%20pairs.), an upper bound for $R$ is $2\times 3.5809=7.1618$ (I multiply by $2$, because in the article the cetral circle has radius $1/2$.) I suspect $R$ could be much lower, maybe around $5$.

Related: [Smallest regular $m$-gon covering a regular $n$-gon](https://mathoverflow.net/q/385442/494920)

Comment: What is meant by the "radius" of a polygon?

Comment: @GerryMyerson By radius I mean the distance from the centre to a vertex. I've added a link to clarify.

Comment: Do you expect the minimum to occur with non-concentric polygons?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, I do. If we assume the polygons have a finite number of sides, then any permutation would have some coprime consecutive polygons, in which case minimizing the outer one would (I think) mean that they are not concentric. On the other hand, in the following permutation the polygons are all minimized and concentric: $s(4),s(3),s(5),s(7),s(9),...$ where $s(k)$ means $k, 2k, 2^2k, ..., 2^\infty k$ but it can be shown that this permutation is not as economical as say $3,s(4),s(6)$ then $s(5),s(7),s(9),...$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446757/all-the-regular-n-gons-are-nested-tightly-around-a-unit-circle-how-to-order-t#comment1154167_446757), I understand what you mean geometrically, but $s(4), s(3), s(5), \dotsc$ is not a permutation of the integers greater than $2$ (because, for example, $3$ has infinitely many predecessors), and similarly for $3, s(4), s(6), s(5), \dotsc$.  Do you mean to allow this situation?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, I mean to allow this situation. Is there a word, instead of permutation, that allows this?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446757/all-the-regular-n-gons-are-nested-tightly-around-a-unit-circle-how-to-order-t#comment1154220_446757), what you want is to impose some order on the natural numbers greater than $2$ that does not necessarily have the same order type as the existing order.  I guess you have to decide what properties you require of this order—almost certainly it should be linear, but, for example, do you want it to be well ordered?  Anyway, you'd need to decide on that, but, even once you do, I'm not sure of any existing terminology.